# Mule 3.3 - How can I pass basic auth credentils to HTTPS outbound endpoint in mule flow

Tags: mule

I want to send new basic auth credential to the https outbound endpoint.
I tried using **message-properties-transformer** but its not working . I am getting fault message.

Is there any other way I can send basic auth credentials ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [explained in the documentation](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/HTTP+Transport+Reference#HTTPTransportReference-SendingCredentials), embed the credentials directly in the endpoint:

```
<https:outbound-endpoint address="https://user:password@mycompany.com/secure" ... />
```